# virt-manager GUI is not opening

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, virtualization, qemu, kvm, ubuntu-server

I have ubuntu 18.04 server in which i have installed below packages to setup kvm:

qemu-kvm libvirt-bin bridge-utils virtinst virt-manager

Virt-manager is failing to open with below error:

**Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused**
**Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused**
**Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused**

**(virt-manager:3026): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:09:54.999: cannot open display:**

I have logged into server with -X option and in my sshd_config file, X11Forwarding is yes.
libvirtd service is active and running.
Output of kvm-ok command is:

**INFO: /dev/kvm exists**
**KVM acceleration can be used**

Can someone help me fix it?